# Assign a const to a constexpr variable

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr

I tried to run a program based on `constexpr`.

Code:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

        const int i = 10;
        constexpr int j = 10;

        constexpr int val1 = i;
        constexpr int val2 = j; 

        return 0;
}
```

In the book I follow, it is mentioned that if you assign a const to a constexpr variable, it is an error.

But my program compiles without any complaints.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The expression `constexpr int val1 = i;` assigns value of `i` to `val1`

Comment: You're not assigning to the `constexpr` variables, you're initializing them. You could write the same as `constexpr int val1{ i };` — with that notation, you see immediately that no assignment is involved.

Answer (score 8):

---

**Ammendment**

celtschk made a good point in the comments below the question. That is, you are not assigning to anything in your code. You are only initializing. Assigning from a `const` to a `constexpr` is indeed an error. So if that's what your book said, then it was not incorrect. However, this would be a strange point to make, since assigning in the other direction (from a `constexpr` to a `const`) is also an error. Anyway, the rest of the answer is under the assumption that when you said "assign", you meant "initialize".

**End of Ammendment**

---

Your book is incorrect (assuming you are not incorrectly paraphrasing what it said). A const integral which is initialized with a constant expression, is itself a constant expression. So `i` is a constant expression, and can be used to further initialize other constant expressions.

quoth the standard, 5.19/2

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the
>   evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9),
>   would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>   ...
>   — an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to:
>   ...
>   — a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression
>   ...

However, note that a const which is not initialized with a constant expression, is of course not a constant expression:

```
int a = 10;
const int b = a;
constexpr int c = b; // error
```

Also note that this *only* applies to integer and enum types. Not, for example floats and doubles.

```
const float a = 3.14;
constexpr float b = a; // error
```

Although some compilers might allow that (I believe MSVC does)

Comment: @user3337714: That answer makes no mention of integrals.

Comment: I understand. I only mentioned because it shows the same example code and understanding. :)