# Initializing a constexpr with a const, -- int vs float

Tags: c++, constexpr

I'm wondering why the integer `ii` is initiallized at compile time, but not the float `ff` here:

```
int main() {
  const int i = 1;
  constexpr int ii = i;

  const float f = 1.0;
  constexpr float ff = f;
 }
```

This is what happens when I try to compile:

```
> g++ -std=c++11 test.cc
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:6:24: error: the value of ‘f’ is not usable in a constant expression
   constexpr float ff = f;
                        ^
test.cc:5:15: note: ‘f’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
   const float f = 1.0;
```

Comment: constant integers are somewhat special in C++

Comment: My money's on incomplete or flawed compiler implementation of the standard. Haven't checked, but that's what my gut tells me... Have you tried with other compilers (e.g. clang++)?

Comment: @Parthean g++ -std=gnu++11 test.cc produced exactly the same results, and clang gives the same in it's own 'language'.

Comment: Pretty much historical reasons. CWG recently [decided against](http://wg21.link/CWG1826) changing the rules here.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Assign a const to a constexpr variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366213/assign-a-const-to-a-constexpr-variable)

Comment: I believe the relevant standardese can be found in the 9th item of § 5.19 ¶ 2 in N3337 but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Constant variables of integral types with constant initializers are *integral constant expressions* (de facto implicitely `constexpr`; see expr.const in ISO C++). `float` is not an integral type and does not meet the requirements for *constant expression* without the use of `constexpr`. (A similar case is why `int` can be but `float` cannot be a template parameter.)

Comment: This would explain things. Analogous behaviour is confirmed among the other integral types (bool, short - long long). Also, see the link provided in @T.C.s comment above for the discussions as to why things are this way.

Comment: So Bjarne misspoke in section 10.4.2 when he said "A const initialized with a constant expression can be used in a constant expression." He gives the int case as an example, not the float...

Comment: The easy fix is to explicitly label the const float f, in the OP as constexpr float f. This is what the standards folks discussed as a possible requirement for ints as well from T.C.'s link.

Comment: Yeah, I would say that that definition by Bjarne is pretty vague. Even in his example just below it, the impossibility of using `const string` breaks that rule for non-literal types.

Comment: Yes, and `constexpr string s = "asdf"; //error`is a better illustration that constexpr require a literal type.

Answer (score 12):

In C++ constant integers are treated differently than other constant types. If they are initialized with a compile-time constant expression they can be used in a compile time expression. This was done so that array size could be a `const int` instead of `#define`d (like you were forced in C):

*(Assume no VLA extensions)*

```
const int s = 10;
int a[s];          // OK in C++
```

Comment: "and if you don't take their address" -- That's not part of the rule. You can take the address of `s`, and still use it as an array length. It's safe because even if you can take `s`'s address, you're not allowed to modify objects defined as `const` regardless of their types.

Comment: @hvd ty. That rule was for initializing in-class a non-static const integer data member. I thought it applied here too.