# differences between const int and const double at compile time

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

While reading this [article](https://medium.com/@developer_notes/constexpr-in-c-a806a4816d77) I come into this example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    const int var1 = 5;
    const double var2 = 8.4;
    std::cout << "var1 " << var1 
              << "   var2 " << var2 <<std::endl;
    constexpr int var3 = var1 + 3;
    constexpr double var4 = var2 + 3.5;
    std::cout << "var3 " << var3 
              << "   var4 " << var4 <<std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

By compiling it you get the error:

```
pippo.C: In function ‘int main()’:
pippo.C:11:36: error: the value of ‘var2’ is not usable in a constant expression
   11 |     constexpr double var4 = var2 + 3.5;
      |                                    ^~~
pippo.C:7:18: note: ‘var2’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
    7 |     const double var2 = 8.4;
      |
```

Why do the `const int` variable can be used in the `constexpr` while the `const double` variable can't ??

I replicated the example and tried to look for a previous question without success.

Comment: `const` integral variable with a constexpr initializer is implicitly `constexpr`.

Comment: Kindly do proper research before asking any question. There are plenty of related SO posts for this. Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to "search and then research".

Comment: Also note that C++ must be learnt using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of by reading online articles. This is explained in any such beginner book. See also dupe: [Initializing a constexpr with a const, -- int vs float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665079/initializing-a-constexpr-with-a-const-int-vs-float)

Answer (score 2):

Generally only `constexpr` variables (or objects whose lifetime begins during the constant evaluation) can be used in constant expression evaluation.

However, for historical reasons from before the invention of `constexpr`, there is an exception for variables of `const`-qualified integral or enumeration type, which, if initialized by a constant expression themselves, are also usable in constant expressions.

If you want to make your life easier, simply ignore this exception and always put `constexpr` on variables that you want to store compile-time constants.

Comment: Interestingly, references also enjoy this privilege. http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#const-3

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am honestly not really sure what that is intended to permit. I have some difficulty parsing the sentence.

Comment: Stuff like this probably: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bvq1h8roM

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, but there is no requirement anymore that references are usable in constant expressions in order to be used in constant expressions. So that seemed redundant. I guess it is still used for https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#9.sentence-3 and https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.7 (although I am a bit confused by the implication of the latter permitting any literal type).